# Angularjs2 array and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

What you meant by the statement  model:any={}; ? in Typescript.Is this any empty array ?Please explain .

Answer (score 1):

This is means that `model` field will have type `:any` and you will be able to assign anything to it. In this case `model:any = {};` it declares new field `model` that contains empty object.

To set an array you need to use `model:Array = [];`. You can also add type for your Array: `model: Array<number> = [];`